# Selenium (Python): Strategy for locating item with inconsistent Xpath

Tags: selenium, xpath

writing a Python selenium script to auto-populate many forms.  On one particular form, I have to add the entry, then click the "Add Another" button in order add the next entry.  I successfully located the "Add Another" button via find.element(By.XPATH, xx), which works on the first two iterations with an xpath that looks like this:

`//*[@id="7d977bf8-9863-5be0-ab89-c90cff57953d"]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/button[1]`

But it is unable to locate the button on the third pass through. I found that the xpath changed ever so slighty:  The index of the second /div in the path changed from "2" to "6":

`//*[@id="7d977bf8-9863-5be0-ab89-c90cff57953d"]/div[3]/div[6]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/button[1]`

My immediate reaction was to code for a NoSuchElementException and if the original is not found, search for the second. But given the observed behavior, I'm not sure I can be certain  it's just those two Xpaths. I may need to "Add Another" 40 or 50 times, I could end up with a block of code that tries 10 or 20 xpaths (I am not a web developer, so I have no idea why this change of path is happening, or when it may happen again on the same Form).

So I'm trying to come up with another method to locate this button.  Here is the HTML:

```
<button class="grid-button" data-bind="click: function() { imagetrend.formComposer.controlHandlers.grid.addAnotherButtonClickHandler($context) }, css: { 'disabled' : imagetrend.FormComposer.isReadOnly($context) }, disableEvent: { 'click': imagetrend.FormComposer.isReadOnly.bind(null, $context) }">                                    <i class="fa fa-lg fa-plus"></i>                                    Add Another                                </button>
```

I don't see any unique element in there that I can search by given what I know about Selenium:  Tag, ID, CSS_Selector...I tried locating by the "fa fa-lg fa-plus" class, but that isn't found (I think I've deduced that's for the large plug sign in the button).

So is there some sort of bulletproof way I can find this element without coding for every potential xpath I find along the way?  Thanks.

Comment: Please share a link to that page. We can't help you without that

Comment: Thanks Prophet.  It's behind a login page :(.  Would the entire HTML for the page help?  Screenshots?

Comment: is this XPATH `//button[@class='grid-button'][text()='Add Another']` not unique ?

Comment: Screenshots will definetely not work since we need to see the HTML, not the picture of the page. The entire HTML maybe will be good, but it can be dynamic, elements may change by some javaScripts, clicks etc.

Comment: Yes, it's definitely dynamic.  The "Page Source" is 2200+ lines, and no references to this element.  I can't figure out a way to copy the entire element tree in the Chrome Developer window.   Stepping through the application, it's always only the second /div index that changes, with no pattern I can discern yet.  There's two other buttons on that menu bar, and that second /div index follows all three.  Is there a way to add a wildcard element in an xpath?

Comment: Why yes, yes there is.  The 'ol asterisk!

Comment: For some reason Akzy's comment wasn't visible to me until now- I will also try that and report back.

Comment: Akzy, many thanks, but that XPATH gives me "element not found".  I'll stick with the asterisk.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find an alternate method to identify that element, but found that with only that second /div index changing, a wildcard character suited my needs.

so it ended up as:

`driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="7d977bf8-9863-5be0-ab89-c90cff57953d"]/div[3]/div[*]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/button[1]').click()`

And that XPATH matches any instance of the button that may pop up.

Thanks to Prophet and Akzy for keeping me on my toes!